# Why I can't compile Flutter Web with sqlite3?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, web, drift

I'm looking to compile my current flutter application to the web and I run into some problem.

My application works well on Android and iOS. I'm using drift and sqlite3 for the mobile and as it's not working on the web, I did the workaround to be able to use it.

I added the 2 files to the web folder (drift_worker.js and sqlite3.wasm) but I can still can launch it.

My first screenshot is the web architecture with the proper documentation from the website

[image]

And this one is the current error

[image]

I tried to flutter clean and etc but nothing change. My current version is 3.16.4 and dart in 3.2.4 and I'm compiling on Chrome(web-javascript).

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Have you tried a minimal web-only project? Note that the imports look different for normal vs web - see https://pub.dev/packages/sqlite3#wasm-web-support You'll probably need conditional imports.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't change the import actually ! I will try that this afternoon and I will let you know, thank you for the tips @RichardHeap

Comment: Alright @RichardHeap, the problem was with drift and not sqlite, I had to put another import and now it's working ! (It's compiling, not working but that's a start :) ), thank you !